# Hyperledger Composer "Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: Error: Invalid results returned ::NOT_FOUND" on windows 10

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I'm trying to run the following blockchain tutorial on Windows 10
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

Everything went fine (all npm installs, fabric tools, download fabric, start fabric, create the project archive, composer runtime install) untill I ran the following command:

```
composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna --file networkadmin.card
```

And
had this error:

Starting business network from archive: tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
Business network definition:
        Identifier: tutorial-network@0.0.1
        Description: Tuto DevWorks

× Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...

```
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: Error: Invalid results returned ::NOT_FOUND
Command failed
```

Previous successful command was:

> composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName
>   tutorial-network √ Installing runtime for business network
>   tutorial-network. This may take a minute... Command succeeded

My configuration is:

- WIN 10
- Node v8.9.1
- npm 5.5.1
- Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
- git version 2.14.1.windows.1

I also tried with another bna archive and had the same issue.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If this message occurs on the stage of instantiating the composer chaincode, one must check that there's a fabric channel defined and peers have joined it.

Answer (score 0):

we don't, at present, support Windows 10. We support the platforms shown here:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/installing/development-tools.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I saw that but wanted to give it a try on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue in MacOS environment. I found that I haven't created the channel and joined the peers. Once I did that, I could start business network and ping.

Comment: Thanks, since I'm new in the domain can you develop a bit? Does this mean that there is an additional step between steps 1) and 2) of the chapter  "Deploying the business network" of this tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html